# Move Library to sidebar

Tags: foobar2000

I am using  Foobar2000 for some time and I can't manage to do one simple thing. I wan't to put my `media library` to the left sidebar, over the `Album art` panel.

[image: Current state]

For now, it works as a separate window. I've installed Foobar on my friend's PC recently and he was able to display his media library as an UI panel so I have no idea why I'm not able to do so. We both using the most up to date Foobar version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because you're using ColumnsUI instead of the default UI.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the Layout that you've customized. You have a couple options:

- Go to `View -> Layout -> Quick Setup` and pick a pre-defined layout to use.
- Go to `View -> Layout -> Enable Layout Editing Mode` and add the album list panel wherever you like.
- If you want to create a fresh view, go to `View -> Layout -> Create Scratchbox` and build a brand-new layout from scratch.